# Can I get CMake to do a git checkout of a project during build

Tags: git, cmake, microcontroller

I see that there is a FindGit module in CMake but can I use that to have CMake check out a specific revision of some software on build?

I'd like to be able to specify several repositories and at build they should all be checked out and built together with my application.

[edit]
To be clear, when I say several repositories and built together I mean that the sources from the repositories should be fetched and that those sources should compile together with my application sources.
The reason being that I want a "platform" consisting of FreeRTOS, LwIP, mbed-tls and so on. This "platform" should be usable from many different projects but since each of the platform components needs to be built with different configurations for different projects I need to compile their sources together with my application. Then it is all linked together and one single hex file is produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=externalproject_add) is what you need.

> [GIT_TAG tag]               # Git branch name, commit id or tag

Comment: I looked at the link but I don't think that is for me. I added some more information that might clear it up. Sorry for the incomplete first question.

Comment: @evading It's exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry. I must have not understood it. I'll look through it more thoroughly.